# Uncaught TypeError: setState is not a function, why isn't it working?

Tags: reactjs, state, use-state

I am using a dropdown box to map through some state data that is already established.

I am wanting the user to be able to make a decision from the dropdown menu, which will then save to its own state...

The  code is this, as you can see the `onChange` is calling the `onExperienceDecision` function:

```
<select className='selectio-box' name="experience-selection" id="experience-selection" onChange={onExperienceDecision}>
  {
    experienceData.myExperiences.map(e => {
      return (
        <option value={e._id}>{e.createdAt}, ({e._id})</option>
      )
    })
  }
</select>
```

The `onExperienceDecision` function code is this:

```
const onExperienceDecision = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const experienceIdChoice = event.target.value;
  setExperienceChoice({value: experienceIdChoice });
  console.log(experienceChoice)
}
```

The confusing part is that if I change the function code to this:

```
const onExperienceDecision = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const experienceIdChoice = event.target.value;
  console.log(experienceIdChoice)
}
```

then the `console.log` is the correct id I am trying to save, it is just when I am trying to save it to state with `setExperienceChoice` I am getting the error.

[image: error]

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you please post the code where `setExperienceChoice` is defined?

Comment: Make sure _setExperienceChoice_ is defined and it is a function. Also ensure that it is available within your component.

Comment: Please can you share the full component code? In case you cannot then try to share as much as possible. Thanks

Comment: const {experienceChoice, setExperienceChoice} = useState("");

this is where I am trying to set State... should it be useState({}) ?

Comment: https://github.com/ThomBurt/flicks2.0-fromMac/blob/master/client/src/pages/SelectMovie/SelectMovie.js


That is the page on GitHub, it is super long and has a lot of code that doesn't apply to this issue!

Setting state at line 46
the function is on line 209
The return is line 341

Answer (score 0):

You need to use square brackets instead of curly braces when declaring a state variable:

```
const [experienceChoice, setExperienceChoice] = useState("");
```